# Nautilus show selected file with better precision

Tags: nautilus

When I select a file in Nautilus down the bottom of the window is a little box telling me the name of the file I have selected and its size. It usually shows something like 6.3 Kb however when I am using large files it becomes unhelpful for quick comparisons between files. For example I might some files that a program output and at a glance I would like to be able to determine their exact  size rather than it rounding to one decimal place. Is there any way to change it?

[image: example screenshot]

Comment: Do you mean the box which I included into your question as example screenshot? (German Nautilus version though...)

Comment: Yeah that’s the one

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in the standard Nautilus aka Files and frankly I do not know a patch for it.

You could use a different file manager, for example, Midnight Commander aka `mc`

```
sudo apt-get install mc
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of a terminal tool, I'd rather suggest a GUI file manager like `nemo` from the Cinnamon Desktop or `thunar` from XFCE. I know that Nemo uses a static status bar outside the file list. Not sure about Thunar currently, but they're at least usually more flexible than Nautilus.