# How to hide the little yellow box which appears when a file in Nautilus is selected?

Tags: nautilus

Does anybody know how to hide the little yellow box which appears when a file in Nautilus is selected? Please see the image below:

[image: little yellow box]
<sub>Image taken from [Nautilus show selected file with better precision](https://askubuntu.com/q/675474/367990) thanks to [user ByteCommander](https://askubuntu.com/users/367990/byte-commander).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by enabling status bar in Nautilus menu > View > Statusbar. After enabling Statusbar, `yellow box` will disappear and it's content will be shown in the Statusbar below the content pane.

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]